# Id is not defined while opening a new JS window

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, custom-button

I have below code that gives out error with Form custom object's Id value as not defined. Can someone please help?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
window.open('/apex/FormTemplatePrinterRequest?'+'id='+{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Id}+'&TemplateId='+{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Form_Template_Name_abvId__c},'_blank');}
```

Comment: Can you please change the question title ?

Comment: A clear title is a good norm

Answer (score 5):

> Apex variables are not part of Javascript runtime, they are rendered from server side.

- You need to enclose the Apex variables with single quote in client side.

Try this:

```
window.open('/apex/FormTemplatePrinterRequest?'+'id='+'{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Id}'+'&TemplateId='+'{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Form_Template_Name_abvId__c}','_blank');}
```

Even though above code will work its better to **JSENCODE** the Apex variables to avoid **XSS** vulnerablity:

```
window.open('/apex/FormTemplatePrinterRequest?id={!JSENCODE(Form_Requests_abv__c.Id)}&TemplateId={!JSENCODE(Form_Requests_abv__c.Form_Template_Name_abvId__c)}','_blank');}
```

If you apply for security review, all these vulnerabilities will raise serious red flags, so its better to follow it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code :

```
window.open('/apex/FormTemplatePrinterRequest?id={!Form_Requests_abv__c.Id}&TemplateId={!Form_Requests_abv__c.Form_Template_Name_abvId__c}','_blank')
```